# How to get contacts associated in a company if the Contact record has empty Company field in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am creating a script that needs to get the contacts associated to a company.  The script needs to work for both Customers and Vendors.

You can attach a Contact to a Customer or Vendor from the record screen and by doing this you can attach a Contact with an empty Company field.

[image]

I can use the sublist contactroles if it is a Customer record but that sublist is not available for the Vendor record.

Is there a way to get the contact records via search?  So using the screenshot above can a search get the following contacts: Aiden Somerhalder, Alex Wolfe and Gerrom Test Contact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create a saved search of Vendors/Suppliers.

Add a filter to your result: contact : name is not empty

Add a column to your result: contact : name

Add a column to your result: contact : internalId

This should give you a set that your script can iterate through.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a vendor or customer search and the search should  return the company/name or more details. Just select as a filter or column:
Contact fields... Company

Perhaps something like this (Running from within the record):

```
var filters = [];
var columns = [];

filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('internalidnumber', null, 'equalto', [nlapiGetRecordId()]));
columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('entityid', 'contact', null));

var results = nlapiSearchRecord(nlapiGetRecordType(), null, filters, columns);
```